# Where are the cookies stored in Chrome? (the file)

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, filepath

I mean, i know the file is in "`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`" or "`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`" and it's a "`Cookies`" named SQL file. But if I delete this file from my computer the cookies will not disappear from the browser. I want to manually delete this, not from Chrome's settings. Please, help me find the correct files and path.